# How to make side bar collapsible manu which won't affect main page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

[image: This is sidebar manu window by default]

[image: This is the window after it expanded]

this is the demo images from random website...

i want to make this type of side bar...
i mean after expand it wont affect the page...

so how to make left side-bar manu?

Comment: You can try adding a `position: fixed` for the navigation wrapper

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: check this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav

Comment: you can see this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

Comment: use `position:fixed` for navigation

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:fixed` and add some z-index to always be on top